# Why isn't light passing through volume scatter?

Tags: materials, light

I am currently following a tutorial and added a cylinder and added a volume scatter node to it. I set the Light Path Volume to 4 when the default is zero. Once it rendered, i realized that light was not passing through it and I could not see any smoke/fog. The object is wired in view port display. If you could help me out thanks. Here is the image of my node setup. If you could help me out. It would be highly appreciated. Thx!

[image]
[image]

Comment: by Light path volume 4 I meant, going to render properties. the place where you change between cycles and rendering. Then going to 'light paths' drop down, that controls how many times the light bounces. I changed the volume number to 4, default is zero. I am using a sun lamp, strength of 6. raising the density made it slightly more darker, I'm not sure. Little to no difference made. lowering it made no difference either. Render time is too long to keep experimenting with values. I am going to post the blend file once it loads. Thx for responding!

Comment: Try using point light or a spot light. Sun is not really a lamp but just light direction.

Comment: that temporarily fixed the problem but it kind of ruins the nature of the scene. Is there any way to do it with the sun? Why won't the sun work the same way as a spotlight? Thanks!

Comment: The sun lamp is not really a lamp, but an abstraction, sets light in one direction. It is a light that is infinitely far away and it doesn't take into consideration the placement on the 3D world. Point light and other lights are light sources in the 3D space.